# Getting Duration of Two DateAndTime in(HH:mm:ss) Format Based on Some Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

duration of DateAndTime in(HH:MM:SS) but i need to select startdate and Enddate by sorting some conditions but duration is getting wrong

```
Start Date                     End date                  Duration
 2018-11-22 17:34:33.00   2018-11-26 10:22:57.00      09:36:48.0000000
```

in the above example DateDiffrence is 98 hours, but its calculated as 9 hours??

```
(SELECT CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(s, SUM(( DATEPART(hh, (B.DateAndTime - A.DateAndTime)) * 3600 ) + ( DATEPART(mi, (B.DateAndTime - A.DateAndTime)) * 60 ) + DATEPART(ss, (B.DateAndTime - A.DateAndTime))), 0)) AS total_time 
FROM (SELECT DateAndTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC) AS S
      FROM Tablename
      WHERE Marker='S'
      and TagIndex=2
      AND a.Val=Val) AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DateAndTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC) AS E 
 FROM Tablename
 WHERE Marker='E'
 and TagIndex=2
 AND a.Val=Val) AS B
ON B.E=A.S) AS Duration)
```

Comment: SQL Server's Time data type can hold values between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` (+ fractions of seconds). If you expect the value to be 98 hours, you can't express that in a time data type.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled for your words, but can you suggest me alternate solution??

Comment: Do not confuse presentation with the actual value. You want to calculate duration using what precision (i.e., which unit of measure)? Minute? Second? Millisecond? When you decide, you calculate that value using datediff (and read the documentation so you understand what it does). Once you have that correct, then and only then do you worry about what consumes that value and how it is used (i.e., displayed to user if needed).

Comment: @SMor ya i understood but when i use the datetime rather then string getting error as Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. in above mentioned query

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,(DATEDIFF(s,'2018-11-22 17:34:33.00','2018-11-26 10:22:57.00')) / 3600 ),2) + ':' 
          + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,(DATEDIFF(s,'2018-11-22 17:34:33.00','2018-11-26 10:22:57.00')) / 60) % 60 ,2) + ':' 
          + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,(DATEDIFF(s,'2018-11-22 17:34:33.00','2018-11-26 10:22:57.00')) % 60 ),2)
```

Comment: Vujic Thank you in my code columns datatype is dateandtime and am getting error as Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string how can i solve this

Comment: Maybe for every datetime you have you can try to cast it as datetime or datetime2, something like this: CAST('2018-11-22 17:34:33.00' AS datetime) or CAST('2018-11-22 17:34:33.00' AS datetime2)

Comment: Vujic Thanks For reply actually is used column as datetime then error getting as Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. as mentioned in above inner query??

Comment: Sorry, but this is beyond my knowledge of sql, this code works for me, hope someone will help you soon!